# Trouble installing Java Netbeans on my Mac (10.6 Snow Leopard)

Tags: java

When I try to install Netbeans the JDK file on my Mac, I keep getting a yellow examination mark, saying "OSCHECK_MESSAGE" which is basically not letting me selecting my HDD as my Destination.

I have already:

- installed and updated my Java.
- Repaired and verified my permissions.
- checked and verified with onyX too.

I checked Google for everything, I came across an identical problem with Mountain Lion, but obviously their solutions are completely different as root folders are different.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's a problem with NetBeans itself. https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=248413 Does an older version of Netbeans work?

Comment: Yeah im reading here taht it doesn't support my system which was not easy to find.

aWhere will i find an older version, or is there any good alternatives for running Java to Netbeans

Comment: There could be older versions on NetBeans site. You could also give either IntelliJ a shot (paid, but 30-day trial) or Eclipse (free)

Comment: What version of netbeans did you try to install?

Comment: JDK 8 but im downloading eclipse now to see if this works thanks for the reply fols ill let yas know